# Content Security Policy intermittent error

Tags: javascript, apache, content-security-policy, nonce

I get an intermittent error when loading a page with a CSP
Firefox: "Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Source: ..."

Chrome "The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''nonce-YVV3G@Kk3ex7GMz53NWHlwAAADs''. It will be ignored.
list:1 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-YVV3G@Kk3ex7GMz53NWHlwAAADs' 'report-sample' ...". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-bcuD/K2TDYJ65gRxOp1yB9QFYhNqCOvbD35Sa/Pn/es='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I am using nonces.
I do not think I have anything inline which is not under a nonce.
Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "report-to '...'; " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "report-uri '...'; " 

Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "object-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "connect-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "worker-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "child-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "form-action 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "manifest-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "media-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'; "

Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'report-sample' ...; " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "img-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'report-sample' ... ; " 
Header set Content-Security-Policy "font-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'report-sample' ...; "
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'report-sample' ...;" 

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains "
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;Secure;SameSite=Strict"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests; "
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'; "
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "form-action 'self'; "
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set X-XSS-Protection "0 "
</IfModule>
```

and in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="'.$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'].'">
```

which results into

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="YVV3G@Kk3ex7GMz53NWHlwAAADs">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID']` is not suitable for `nonce`:

1. it does not generate cryptographically secure values.
2. the value generated can contain the `@` character invalid for `'nonce-value'` - that's why error has intermittent behaviour.

Instead of UNIQUE_ID do use [mod_cspnonce](https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce) for Apache 2.